# How to call procedure in aspx.cs file to return true or false when record found in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

i wrote a procedure which return 1 and 0 which given below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckPI]
  @PI Varchar(50)

AS BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @Exists INT

  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Tbl_ILSM_Quotation WHERE QuotationNo = @PI)
  BEGIN
        SET @Exists = 1
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
        SET @Exists = 0
  END

  RETURN @Exists
 // when i execute this code in sql then it gives right ans 
  DECLARE @ReturnValue INT 
  EXEC @ReturnValue = @ReturnValue
  SELECT @ReturnValue
  END
```

and aspx.cs file

```
 protected string GetPI()
     {
         int customerId = GetCustomerID(); // customer id - 123
         int year = Convert.ToInt32(ddlIdYear.SelectedValue);
         string PI = "PI/" + year + "/" + customerId; // PI - PI/2017/123
         //SqlDataReader myReader = null;
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JSSConnection"].ToString());
         con.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CheckPI", con);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PI", PI);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@ReturnValue", DbType.Boolean);
         sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
         cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //int retrnval = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
         con.Close();
         //Response.Write(cmd.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value);

         return PI;

     }
```

i made procedure to check that pi number is available or not in database if available then return 1 otherwise 0
then i call that SP in aspx.cs file but i am unable to check that what it return after execution 1 or 0

Comment: 1) [`RETURN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql) exits the stored procedure immediately, any commands after that are ignored. 2) there is also a [`ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection.aspx). 3) `ExecuteNonQuery` is enough, no need to also do a `ExecuteScalar`. 4) you are ignoring `retrnval`

Comment: The parameter direction is not output it is `ReturnValue`. But you should use `Output` because return value is, by convention, a report of success or fail, not an actual data result.

Comment: Dp you really need a stored procedure for this simple task?

Comment: @HansKesting can you give me some idea that how can i get true false or 1 and 0 in aspx.cs file when value available in database.

Comment: @AviKashyap Change that `@ReturnValue` parameter: set it's type to integer and direction to ReturnValue. Then do ExecuteNonQuery. Then read the value of that `@ReturnValue` parameter (use Convert.ToInt32 on the Value property).

Comment: i am not getting your point @HansKesting can you please correct my code. which return true false or 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Add an Out param to capture the return value from the Procedure
SqlParameter outParam = new SqlParameter();
outParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
outParam.ParameterName = “@outParam”;
outParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(outParam);

// Add an Out param to capture whether the Stored Proc executed correctly or not (exception)
SqlParameter retParam = new SqlParameter();
retParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
retParam.ParameterName = “@retParam”;
retParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(retParam);

// Execute the command
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Get the values
int retval = (int)cmd.Parameters[“@retParam”].Value;
int outval = (int)cmd.Parameters[“@outParam”].Value; // Should contain the value you've returned for existence of PI value
```

You've used INT to represent a boolean, you can change it to BIT within the Stored Proc to keep it consistent.

Comment: when i add int retval = (int)cmd.Parameters[“@retParam”].Value; then it gives syntax error

Comment: Please add the error details. May be the value is returning null and typecasting is throwing exception

Comment: when i added your code  after cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;=== // Add an Out param to capture the return value from the Procedure it gives Procedure or function CheckPI has too many arguments specified. error

Comment: I meant what error you're getting or the error message

Comment: Procedure or function CheckPI has too many arguments specified

Comment: Ok, then comment out adding the retParam and it's reference and see if it works.

Comment: The stored procedure only has a `@PI` input parameter, plus the `@retParam` return variable (name is *not* important, the direction *is*). So remove all mention of the `@outParam`. And keep the `@PI`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of these lines:

```
     SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@ReturnValue", DbType.Boolean);
     sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

use this:

```
     SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@ReturnValue", DbType.Int32);
     sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

The value returned (with the `RETURN` statement) from the stored proc is always an integer, not a boolean (or string). So the type of the parameter needs to be changed. Plus you need the *return* value, as you didn't declare any output parameter, so you need a different direction.

Next you execute the query with

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

There is no select statement that returns values (everything after the RETURN in your stored proc is ignored), so this is enough.
After the execution, you can inspect the returned value:

```
int retVal = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value);
```

Then you can use that retVal variable, for instance by using `return retVal == 1;`. But then you need to change the return type of your method from `string` to `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem. and answer is given below

Stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckPI]
@PI Varchar(50),
@Exists INT = 0 out

AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Tbl_ILSM_Quotation WHERE QuotationNo = @PI)
BEGIN
    SET @Exists = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Exists = 0
END
```

and aspx.cs file code

```
protected string GetPI()
     {
         int customerId = GetCustomerID(); // customer id - 123
         int year = Convert.ToInt32(ddlIdYear.SelectedValue);
         string PI = "PI/" + year + "/" + customerId;
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JSSConnection"].ToString());
         con.Open();
         for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
         {
            PI = "PI/" + year + "/" + customerId + i; // PI - PI/2017/123
            //SqlDataReader myReader = null;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CheckPI", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PI", PI);
            SqlParameter outputParameter = new SqlParameter();
            outputParameter.ParameterName = "@Exists";
            outputParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
            outputParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(outputParameter);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(outputParameter.Value.ToString());

            if (returnVal == 1)
            {
                continue;

            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
         //else
         //{

         //    PI = "PI/" + year + "/" + customerId;
         //}

         con.Close();
         //Response.Write(cmd.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value);

         return PI;

     }
```